# How to benchmark (/interpret results of a benchmark) a Go webserver under load?

Tags: go, webserver, benchmarking

Broadly, I'm trying to answer the question "which of two approaches to handling incoming requests is more efficient". I'm measuring efficiency by:

- lower max RAM use
- lower percentage of CPU usage

These metrics will *hopefully* signal which approach is more suited to running on a resource-constrained server. It's gets a lot of volume, so the most important thing is that we can process requests faster than they come in. We've had "too many open files" problems when our queue filled up and the server had too many open connections.

So, tach of the two programs aims to respond to the initial request as quickly as possible and then queue up the actual work. In real life, it's an outgoing HTTP request; in my tests, it's a `sleep` for a variable amount of time, to try to simulate inconsistent conditions.

Here's the first program:

```golang
// approach A: spin up a few goroutines at the start 
// and send messages into a long buffered channel

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "time"
)

const (
    minResponseTimeSec = 0.5
    maxResponeTimeSec  = 2.5
)

var messageChan = make(chan int, 1024)

func randResponseTime() float64 {
    return minResponseTimeSec + rand.Float64()*(maxResponeTimeSec-minResponseTimeSec)
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    for i := 1; i <= 8; i++ {
        go worker()
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/message", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil))
}

func handler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    messageChan <- 3 // would normally send POST body
    fmt.Fprint(writer, "ok\n")
}

func worker() {
    for range messageChan {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(randResponseTime()))
    }
}
```

and here's the second:

```golang
// approach B: set a maximum number of concurrent
// goroutines and spin them up as needed

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "time"
)

const (
    minResponseTimeSec = 0.5
    maxResponeTimeSec  = 2.5
)

var (
    semaphoreChan chan struct{}
)

func randResponseTime() float64 {
    return minResponseTimeSec + rand.Float64()*(maxResponeTimeSec-minResponseTimeSec)
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    semaphoreChan = make(chan struct{}, 1024)

    http.HandleFunc("/message", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil))
}

func handler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    semaphoreChan <- struct{}{}
    go fanout() // would normally send POST body

    fmt.Fprint(writer, "ok\n")
}

func fanout() {
    defer func() { <-semaphoreChan }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(randResponseTime()))
}
```

With each program running (separately) I used `ab` to send lots of requests at each in turn. But, I'm having trouble interpreting the data available at `/profile/pprof`. I was focusing on the stats at the bottom of `/debug/pprof/heap?debug=1`, especially `TotalAlloc` and `HeapAlloc`. But, those numbers all seem to grow indefinitely (as I refresh the page), while I'd expect them to stay flat before / after the benchmarking is done, which leads me to think I'm looking at the wrong numbers.